# Como reduzir número de loops para calcular menor diferença entre todos os números de uma lista?

Tags: python, loop

O programa abaixo retorna a menor diferença possível entre todos os elementos de uma lista:

```py
def calculo(A):
    r = float("inf")
    n = len(A)
    for i in range(0, n-1):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if abs(A[i] - A[j]) < r:
                r = abs(A[i] - A[j])
    print(r)
```

Mas estou cansado de escrever todos os códigos que precisam comparar pares de elementos de uma mesma lista, como se estivesse escrevendo um bubble sort.

Como reduzo o número de loops no código acima? Qual o princípio pra começar a se pensar diferente e começar a escrever códigos mais eficientes?

Comment: Talvez o segundo `for` devesse ser: `for j in range(i+1, n):`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma alternativa é primeiro ordenar a lista, e depois percorrê-la apenas uma vez, calculando a diferença entre cada elemento e o próximo. Como a lista estará ordenada, não é necessário calcular a diferença entre o primeiro e o terceiro, por exemplo, pois certamente será maior ou igual à diferença entre o primeiro e o segundo.

```
def menor_diferenca(lista):
    r = float("inf")
    lista = sorted(lista)
    for i in range(len(lista) - 1):
        diff = abs(lista[i] - lista[i + 1])
        if diff < r:
            r = diff
    return r
```

Claro que ordenar a lista tem o seu custo, mas [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), o algoritmo usado é o [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), que garante um bom desempenho (O(n logn) no pior caso), o que já é melhor que dois loops aninhados.

> *Um detalhe é que seu segundo loop não está certo. Por exemplo, quando `i` for `3`, você faz um `for j in range(1, n)`, ou seja, `j` também passará pelo índice `3` e aí a diferença será zero (se a lista não tiver valores repetidos, o resultado será - erroneamente - zero). Então na verdade este loop deve começar em `i + 1`.*

---

Fazendo uma comparação básica, usando o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) para medir os tempos:

```
def com_loop(lista):
    r = float("inf")
    n = len(lista)
    for i in range(0, n - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            diff = abs(lista[i] - lista[j])
            if diff < r:
                r = diff
    return r

def com_sort(lista):
    r = float("inf")
    lista = sorted(lista)
    for i in range(len(lista) - 1):
        diff = abs(lista[i] - lista[i + 1])
        if diff < r:
            r = diff
    return r


import random
# gerando uma lista com 1000 números aleatórios
numeros = random.sample(range(1, 1000000), 1000)

import timeit

print(timeit.repeat('com_loop(numeros)', repeat=3, number=100, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.repeat('com_sort(numeros)', repeat=3, number=100, globals=globals()))
```

O tempo de execução exato varia de uma máquina para outra, e mesmo na mesma máquina pode ter variações entre uma execução ou outra, mas só para ter uma ideia, o resultado que obtive foi:

```
[24.693826, 24.928060100000003, 25.2158304]
[0.13898210000000688, 0.14047560000000203, 0.10606690000000185]
```

Ou seja, os *loops* aninhados levaram cerca de 24 segundos, enquanto o algoritmo percorrendo a lista ordenada demorou por volta de 0,13 segundos.

Também coloquei o código em IDE's online e o resultado foi bem similar (a versão com a lista ordenada é bem mais rápida que os dois *loops*). Veja no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/QuizzicalPlayfulBug#main.py) e no [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YP13ro) (neste último tive que diminuir a quantidade de execuções para não estourar o tempo limite do site).

---

Você também poderia usar [`lista.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) para ordenar a lista. A diferença é `lista.sort()` modifica a própria lista, enquanto [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) retorna outra lista.

Comment: Muito obrigado por todo o detalhe, e pelo benchmark, impressionante como n.log(n) cresce tão menor que exponencial. Eu realmente não tinha me tocado que com a lista ordenada só precisaria iterar uma vez, e não conhecia sobre timsort, pra mim, quicksort era a melhor opção disponível